# how can i give limit Repeat function in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

This is my script but i need limit in mysql result i used before LIMIT in mysql query but it's not worked.

```
function display_menus($parent_id = 0){
 $i=0;
 $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer_dog_details_db WHERE dog_id_parent = '$parent_id'  && username='root' && dog_id_filter='$_GET[dog_id]'");

if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){

  echo "<ul class='tree'>";

    while ($row  = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
      echo "<li><a href=''><span style='font-size:14px;'>". $row['dog_name'] ."</span>";
      echo "<br> ". $row['dog_id'] ." <br>";
      echo "". $row['sex'] ."<br>";
      echo "".$row['whelped_date']."<br>";
      echo "</a>";
      display_menus($row['dog_id']);
      echo "</li>";
    }

  echo "</ul>";
 }
}

display_menus();
```

Comment: What's the problem? What output are you expecting? What is actually getting rendered? PS: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection big time

Comment: it's a pedigree of dogs i need only 2 generations and i have 5 generations data in my database.

Comment: i,m trying before 
SELECT * FROM customer_dog_details_db WHERE dog_id_parent = '$parent_id' LIMIT 7

but it's not work

Answer (score 0):

```
use:
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer_dog_details_db WHERE dog_id_parent = '$parent_id' AND username='root' AND dog_id_filter='$_GET[dog_id]' limit 0,1");

instead of:

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer_dog_details_db WHERE dog_id_parent = '$parent_id' && username='root' && dog_id_filter='$_GET[dog_id]'");
```

Comment: USE AND instead of &&

Comment: no i don't receive any error but sql show complete data from the database.